# Licensing with Technet/MSDN Server 2008 Enterprise running production VM's with regular licenses

Tags: hyper-v, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I'm wondering about running a massive physical server with Server 2k8r2 enterprise from Technet or MSDN, running a couple of Hyper-V VM's for development (using the same license) but then also run a couple of VM's for production, and buying actual licenses for those production VM's.

is this setup allowed?

thanks

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you asked them?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no licensing expert, but I'm going to say absolutely not. The [MSDN use rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx) are pretty clear that you can only use the license for test/dev/demo, and that you (and other MSDN license holders) are the only person who can access said software.

Once you put a production VM onto your Hyper-V server, it becomes a production server, and needs its own license.

Even if you don't believe it becomes a production server, each person you would want to access the VM would need an MSDN license, and at that point getting a regular license is probably cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

No. Especially the part of running the physical machine with an Evaluation license.

Nice idea, though ...

Answer (score 0):

ok, i thought so. thanks for the responses..

However, this does look like an option-

http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/default.aspx

Hyper-V Server is free, so i can combine dev VM's and production VM's in a physical server. i was just hoping to avoid the Core interface..